# Using IPN to verify successful payment on PayPal

Tags: iframe, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using PayPal hosted pages for payments on my site. I pass return url when creating `SECURETOKEN` used in iframe url. After client successful payment, I get browser postback from PayPal on return url passed when `SECURETOKEN` was created. What happens from time to time is that user close tab before I get postback, saying transaction is approved, and I can't mark it as approved in my local DB.

Workaround was to create IPN listener, and update my local records when I receive valid IPN request.

Now the issue is, I miss some params that I'm getting in iframe postback, that are mandatory, such as `ACC`, `EXPTIME`, `PNREF`.

As far as I can read, `IPN` will NEVER send those data in it's request. Can this be overridden within paypal manager? If not, can anyone suggest any solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I think the whole approach is wrong. You should mark the  transaction as completed when you receive the money, and not before, i.e. when you get the IPN. Nothing else makes business sense. The extra parameters should be saved in the database untiil you get the IPN.

Comment: @EJP maybe I haven't explain whole flow, but yes, I do not mark transaction as approved until it is approved. Extra parameters are saved in same resource as payments, but they are ignored in all business processes  until I get verification from IPN or some other PayPal verified postback

Comment: So your problem is what?

Comment: @EJP  I miss some params that I'm getting in iframe postback, that are mandatory, such as ACC, EXPTIME, PNREF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by enabling [Silent POST url](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#silent-posts) feature in my paypal manager, so same server to server postback will be fired regardless of client closing browser, after payment is accepted.